# How to fetch data into shuttle apex oracle

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

I have a problem with a shuttle page item! So, i have a 2 entities, the first one is Car, the second one is Car Type. When i add a new Car (the new car gets added into the Car table), i do a submit and then the user can choose on the same page (a new shuttle appears with all the car types) what types the car is (i have a table Cars_in_types which is a joint table and contains the id of the car and the id's of the car types).

My problem is the following: when i set the car types they get saved in the joint table as they should, but when i open to edit another car entity, it shows the changes for the last car (even though in db everything is saved as it should). For example, i have car A, which is of type SUV and this gets saved into the db. I have another car B which is shown to be SUV (even though in db it is not since there isn't anything in the joint table for the car B), so i remove the SUV from the right side of the shuttle and i add the type Cabriolet (this gets saved into db for the car B). When i get back to edit car A's types, i see Cabriolet instead of SUV. How do I fix this? The region for type reads data from the joint table.

Answer (score 0):

Car info is stored into `cars` table, while its type is stored into `cars_in_types` table. Why do you need another table? Can one car belong to two (or more) different types? I guess so, otherwise you wouldn't create such a data model.

You didn't share Shuttle item's LoV query (I presume it is a LoV; is it?). Does it select only from `car_types` table (I guess it exists), or does it also reference `:P1_CAR_ID` page item? If latter, then try to set **Parent item(s)** shuttle item property (you'll find it under "Cascading list of values") so that new car ID "refreshes" shuttle item and shows data related to that car.

---

On the other hand, if you meant to do it *properly* / normalized by creating a separate table (`cars_in_types`) so that that table would contain pairs of [`car_id - car_type_id`], that's a nice idea. However, that's not how Apex Shuttle item works. If you select several types and store data, their IDs are stored as a colon-separated list, e.g. `1:18:32` so - from that point of view - you could have saved type(s) into `cars` table.

Because, the way you did it now, once you edit certain car's data, Apex has to know how to access `cars_in_types` and fetch row(s) related to current car ID. If it were the same table, no such problem.

Comment: i need another table so that many cars can be of type Electric and of type Cabriolet in the same time (also many cars can be of type Electric only). I need this so that later on when i do the shopping part, a user can filter what types of cars are shown on the page. Also, this type table is generic (it can hold different types, such as what resource it uses, is it new or used etc). The LOV for the shuttle is CAR_TYPE.

Comment: When i set the LOV to be a query and to read from the joint table where car_Id = :p1_car_id, it only showed me the types from the joint table on the left side, and not all the types on the left side - selected ones on the right side.

Comment: please don't mix 2 issues. This question is about the shuttle. I'd suggest filing another question about your data model. From your description, you could use a bit of guidance there (no offence)

Comment: @Koen Lostrie my data model is completely fine. It is M:N cardinality, so i need another table. What suggested goes against 1NF. I kindly say to everyone, if you know how i can fix the shuttle to do the desired functionality, do so. If not, avoid commenting in vain (No offence to anyone)!

Comment: @vwxyzvwxyz I tend to disagree. There is the fuel (electric/diesel/gas) and the type of car (convertible/sub/saloon/estate). Those are 2 individual 1:1 attributes for a car. so they just should be 2 columns. You can put those into the same attribute but that doesn't make sense (to me). Anyway, it's your data model, you don't have to take my advice. As for the shuttle.... Please post a proper reproducible case. It is very hard to reproduce an issue based on text only. We cannot see your implementation.

Comment: I managed to fix it by making the shuttle a checkbox group, and then using a dynamic action that would automatically check the checkboxes with the types on page load. It achieves the functionality to choose types, but this whole thing with shuttles is just weird to me, or i am just not used to work with them...